# Transformation matrix from principal angles and vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

If I got it right, given two planes in $N$-dimensional space ($N\gg2$), their 2 [principal angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angles_between_flats) ($\theta_1$, $\theta_2$) and 4 vectors ($\vec{a}_1$, $\vec{a}_2$, $\vec{b}_1$, $\vec{b}_2$) can be found, such that the first plane is defined by the vectors $\vec{a}_1$ and $\vec{a}_2$, the second plane by the vectors $\vec{b}_1$ and $\vec{b}_2$, and $\vec{a}_i·\vec{b}_i=\cos\theta_i \;\{i=1,2\}$.

Is it possible to define a unitary matrix that will transform $\vec{a}_i$ into $\vec{b}_i$ (and correspondingly to any other vector, contained or not in the plane)? Intuitively, I think this transformation is not unique, so I would be interested in the "minimal" one (for two vectors in 3D, there's not a unique 3D rotation that brings one to the other, but there's a "minimal" one, that just rotates around their mutual perpendicular).

Complementarily, given two sets of $m$ orthonormal vectors in $N$-dimensional space spanning the same subspace, can I get the matrix that transforms one into the other? This I believe should be unique.

Comment: Did you have a particular value of $N$ in mind? It is not true in general that two planes in an $N$-dimensional space have exactly $2$ principal angles: the number of principal angles depends on $N$. For instance, if $N=3$ (and assuming the planes intersect in a line) then there is only $1$ principal angle.

Comment: No particular value of $N$, but assuming $N\gg2$ (edited the question). I also thought that in 2 dimensions the planes still have 2 principal angles, but at least one of them must be zero, and the principal vector for the angle that's zero is precisely the line along which the planes intersect.

Comment: Since you are concerned with $N>>2$, then take a closer look at the wikipedia link you give, which will show that it takes $>>2$ principle angles.

Comment: I don't think so. Following that notation, I have $\sigma+\tau+\alpha=2$, $\sigma+\nu+\alpha=2$. $\sigma$ is the number of dimensions where the planes intersect, $\tau$ and $\nu$ are the number of perpendicular dimensions, $\alpha$ is the number of principal angles (or, according to other sources, the number of principal angles not equal to 0 or $\pi/2$). So $\alpha$ must be 0, 1, or 2, and by allowing 0 or $\pi/2$ angles, it's always 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have worked it out. Start from two $n\times2$ matrices, $A$ and $B$, each with orthonormal columns (basis vectors of the two planes). Obtain the principal angles ($\theta_1, \theta_2$) and vectors ($\vec{u}_1, \vec{u}_2, \vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2$) through SVD of $A^TB$. The vectors are the columns of the matrices $U$ and $V$ respectively ([see this PDF](http://math.ucdenver.edu/~aknyazev/research/papers/sisc02.pdf)).

Now, each pair $\vec{u}_i,\vec{v}_i$ forms a [plane of rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_of_rotation), corresponding to the angle $\theta_i$. Since all these planes are mutually orthogonal, in the subspace spanned by $\vec{u}_1,\vec{u}_2,\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2$ the rotation matrix is simple to write, but we must have an orthonormal basis for this subspace. $\vec{u}_i$ and $\vec{v}_i$ are in general not orthogonal, they form an angle $\theta_i$, but we can get a vector orthogonal to $\vec{v}_i$, in the same plane:

$$\vec{w}_i = \frac{\vec{u}_i-\cos\theta_i\vec{v}_i}{\sin\theta_i}$$

and now the matrix $X$ formed by the columns $\vec{w}_1,\vec{v}_1,\vec{w}_2,\vec{v}_2$ is an orthonormal basis for this subspace, where the transformation matrix is:

$$M = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta_1 &-\sin\theta_1 & 0 & 0 \\
\sin\theta_1 & \cos\theta_1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cos\theta_2 &-\sin\theta_2 \\
0 & 0 & \sin\theta_2 & \cos\theta_2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore, $XMX^T$ transforms $U$ directly into $V$. But it also projects out all components orthogonal to the planes of rotation, and I want to keep them intact. These orthogonal components can be obtained with $I-XX^T$, so I need: $R=I-XX^T+XMX^T = I + X(M-I)X^T$.

$M$ is $4\times4$, $X$ is $n\times4$, but $R$ is $n\times n$, and I don't want to store that if $n\gg2$, so to transform an arbitrary vector $\vec{c}$, I do:

$$\begin{align}
M'&=(M-I)X^T\\
\vec{c}' &= M'\vec{c} \\
R\vec{c} &= \vec{c} + X\vec{c}'
\end{align}$$

and I only need to store $M'$ and $X$ (of $n\times 4$ size).

Alright, this transforms the subspace spanned by $A$ into the subspace spanned by $B$, leaving the orthogonal complement unaltered. But it doesn't transform $A$ into $B$ (it transforms $U$ into $V$). There is an additional internal rotation within the subspace needed for that. This can be obtained by noting that $A$ will be transformed into $VU^TA$, so the additional rotation to bring this into $B$ is:

$$P=B(VU^TA)^T=BA^TUV^T$$

But this is an $n\times n$ matrix. It's easier to work in $V$ basis, where $B$ is $V^TB$ and $A$ transforms into $U^TA$, therefore:

$$P_V=V^TBA^TU$$

which is a $2\times2$ matrix. Analogously to the above, this additional internal rotation becomes:

$$R^I=I+V(P_V-I)V^T$$

But $V$ is contained in $X$, so it is trivial to express $P$ in the $X$ basis:

$$P_X=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & P_V(1,1) & 0 & P_V(1,2) \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & P_V(2,1) & 0 & P_V(2,2) \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

and

$$R^I=I+X(P_X-I)X^T$$

To fully transform any vector in the $n$-dimensional space, the two transformations $R$ and $R^I$ can be applied consecutively, or the full transformation:

$$\begin{align}
R^F&=R^IR=(I+X(P_X-I)X^T)(I+X(M-I)X^T) \\
&=I+X(P_X-I+M-I+(P_X-I)(M-I))X^T \\
&=I+X(P_XM-I)X^T \\
&=I+X(F-I)X^T \\
F&=P_XM
\end{align}$$

which should give $R^FA=B$, and $R^F\vec{d}=\vec{d}$ if $\vec{d}$ is orthogonal to $A$ and $B$.

I'm sure this can be simplified, but hope it will be useful anyway. It is straightforward to extend this to $m$-dimensional subspaces, by using $m$ and $2m$ instead of 2 and 4.